# what are the checklist when looking at MySQL database for first time?

Tags: mysql

What should I put on my checklist when I look at MySQL database for the first time? I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is very general and I'd suggest clarifying it with more context, but I'll give it a shot.

I would look at:

- security.  What are the users that have privileges on that database?  What are the privileges (i.e. read-only on specific tables, or do they have `grant option` permissions)?
- entities.  What are the major entities and their relationships?
- performance.  What queries are resource hogs?  Are appropriate indexes in place?
- denormalization.  Is the schema purposely denormalized?  If so, why and is it appropriately denormalized?
- foreign keys.  Are they enforced (do the tables use InnoDB)?
- size.  What are the biggest tables?  Which tables are expected to grow the fastest?